# Why does Amazon Web Services have a lengthy url for login page

Tags: security, http, web-applications, web, amazon-web-services

I am wondering why Amazon Web Services console login page has that lengthy url? Why not just POST the data without showing the lengthy url with lots of data in it. Is there any good reason to implement this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a security question because if we can intercept http request we can read get or post request.

I think it's an implementation question. With get request you can :

- create cache mechanism.
- save configuration
- save configuration client side by adding url to your favorite

It's only supposition maybe there are another good reason but I don't think security reason.

For security HTTP vs HTTPS is more important than POST vs GET

Comment: Found this [article](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/08/20/caching-http-post-requests-and-responses/) regarding cache mechanism in POST requests ( by digesting body and appending it to url to evaluate cache key )

Comment: That's a good remark but about caching post request your article say the server has to hash the post request that produce extra server calculation. and this litlle treatment times millions request is a lot of treatment